Spring boot error "An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist"
I was changing the database of my project from H2 to SQLite, and these errors appeared. How can I fix them?
Description:
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:
org.sqlite.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect.<init>(SQLiteDialect.java:58)

The following method did not exist:
'void org.sqlite.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect.registerColumnType(int, java.lang.String)'

The calling method's class, org.sqlite.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect, was loaded from the following location:
jar:file:/C:/Users/hbyeon/.m2/repository/com/github/gwenn/sqlite-dialect/0.1.4/sqlite-dialect-0.1.4.jar!/org/sqlite/hibernate/dialect/SQLiteDialect.class

The called method's class, org.sqlite.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect, is available from the following locations:
jar:file:/C:/Users/hbyeon/.m2/repository/com/github/gwenn/sqlite-dialect/0.1.4/sqlite-dialect-0.1.4.jar!/org/sqlite/hibernate/dialect/SQLiteDialect.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:
org.sqlite.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect: file:/C:/Users/hbyeon/.m2/repository/com/github/gwenn/sqlite-dialect/0.1.4/sqlite-dialect-0.1.4.jar
org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect: file:/C:/Users/hbyeon/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/orm/hibernate-core/6.5.3.Final/hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar

Action:
Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.sqlite.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
This is my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>3.3.5</version>
       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>task</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>task</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
       <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
       <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
       <connection/>
       <developerConnection/>
       <tag/>
       <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
       <java.version>23</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
          <optional>true</optional>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
          <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.github.gwenn</groupId>
          <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
          <version>0.1.4</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
          <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
          <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
          <optional>true</optional>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
       <plugins>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <configuration>
                <excludes>
                   <exclude>
                      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                   </exclude>
                </excludes>
             </configuration>
          </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

And this is my application.properties
spring.application.name=task

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:mydatabase.db
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.sqlite.JDBC

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Previously, I had a error saying "Unable to resolve name org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect", which I resolved by adding the sqlite-dialect dependency to my pom.xml file. However, now these new errors are appearing.
And with this error, I tried to delete the .m2 folder in c:\users\ and close the project and open again, but not working.

You need proper version of sqlite-dialect

First of all, why would you want to switch from h2 to sqlite? They both run in memory and are very similar after all, but H2 has better Hibernate support. HyperHQL is also a valid alternate.

you could downgrade Hibernate to 5.x, which is compatible with sqlite-dialect. Update your spring-boot-starter-parent version in the POM file to use Spring Boot 2.x, which bundles Hibernate 5.x.

@NarenD Spring 5.3 (Spring-boot 2.7) had its End-of-Life in August 2024 and should not be used, because security vulnerabilities can not be fixed in a timely fashion. Please don't recommend this.

This is the correct setting of SQLite dialect for Hibernate:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-community-dialects</artifactId>
</dependency>

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.community.dialect.SQLiteDialect

Based on: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/sqlite-not-working-with-hibernate-6-2/8174/2

ohh thank you:D it's working fine now, thank you:)

Cool. Thanks for feedback. Please accept my answer.
